# How to conditionally reuse the current window to display a buffer?

Tags: buffers, display-buffer-alist

`M-x view-echo-area-messages` (bound to `C-h e` by default) is used to see the *Messages* buffer.

I would like to get the following behavior when I press `C-h e`:

1. If the frame has just 1 window, split the frame to create a new window and show *Messages* in that new window.
2. If the frame already has 2 or more windows, display *Messages* in the other window (not the current one).
3. If the current window is already displaying *Messages* buffer, do NOT do anything (I tend to press `C-h e` by mistake even when I am in the *Messages* buffer).

I am able to achieve points 1 and 2 above using the below:

```el
;; Control where the *Messages* buffer opens
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("\\*Messages\\*" . ((display-buffer-reuse-window
                                    display-buffer-pop-up-window)
                                   . ((inhibit-same-window . t)))))
```

But with the above elisp snippet, if I am already in a window with *Messages* and if I do `C-h e`, it pops up another window displaying the same buffer.

I basically need emacs to ignore `(inhibit-same-window . t)` if the current buffer matches `"\\*Messages\\*"`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @Drew's solution works as I wanted, I was looking for a generic solution that I can apply to multiple cases; not just to *Messages* buffer.

### Step 1: General Setup

Advise `display-buffer` to not execute if the current buffer is same as the
to-be-displayed buffer if the new ALIST entry `inhibit-duplicate-buffer`
is non-nil.

```el
(defun modi/execute-display-buffer-if-nil (buffer-or-name &optional action frame)
  "This functions advices `display-buffer' such that `display-buffer' gets
executed only if this function returns `nil'.

This function returns `t' when below two conditions are true:
1. BUFFER-OR-NAME has a matching entry in `display-buffer-alist' with a
   non-nil `inhibit-duplicate-buffer' entry in its ALIST.
2. BUFFER-OR-NAME is same as the current buffer."
  ;; logic borrowed from the `display-function' definition
  (if (null display-buffer-function)
      (let* ((user-action
              (display-buffer-assq-regexp
               (buffer-name buffer-or-name) display-buffer-alist action))
             ;; end of borrowed logic
             (inhibit-duplicate-buffer (cdr (assq 'inhibit-duplicate-buffer user-action))))
        (and inhibit-duplicate-buffer ; condition 1
             (equal buffer-or-name (window-buffer)))) ; condition 2
    nil))
(advice-add 'display-buffer :before-until #'modi/execute-display-buffer-if-nil)
```

*Note that this advice style needs emacs 24.4+.*

### Step 2: Configuration specific to *Messages* buffer

Use `display-buffer-alist` to set the buffer displaying rules for *Messages* buffer; now setting a non-nil value for the new ALIST entry `inhibit-duplicate-buffer`.

```el
;; Control where to display the *Messages* buffer
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("\\*Messages\\*" . ((display-buffer-reuse-window
                                    display-buffer-pop-up-window)
                                   . ((inhibit-duplicate-buffer . t)
                                      (inhibit-same-window      . t)))))
```

Comment: I realized I don't need the above complicated solution. With the `shackle` package, I simply need to add `("*Messages*" :select nil :other t)` to the `shackle-rules` alist.

Answer (score 4):

```el
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (equal "*Messages*" (buffer-name (window-buffer)))
    (display-buffer "*Messages*" (if (one-window-p)
                                     'display-buffer-pop-up-window
                                   'display-buffer-reuse-window))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-h e") 'foo)
```

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like it inhibits opening the buffer in the same window by default when it does `display-buffer-reuse-window`.

Comment: Interesting.. from the source code of `display-buffer`, if the second arg `action` is non-nil and NOT a list (in the `let` form .. `(inhibit-same-window (and action (not (listp action))))`), `inhibit-same-window` is set to `t`.